# React functional component popups based on each id click on edit

Tags: reactjs

I have to add and edit person's experience details through reactjs popups, so that I have Experience component, ExperienceAddPopup component, and ExperienceEditPopup component. So on each click on add(+) button there appears a popup to add person's experience details. This thing is working fine.

Also on click of edit button popup shows but without datas. Now my issue is all the added details I have to edit on click on each edit button (pencil image) based on each clicked id's (not working). how to pass ids on edit modal popups here on edit click?

[image]

Here is my code

Experience.js component

```
   import React, {useState, useEffect, Component } from "react";
    import axios from 'axios';
    import { Modal } from 'react-bootstrap';
    import ExperienceAddPopup from "./ExperiencePopup";
    import ExperienceEditPopup from "./ExperienceEditPopup";
    
    
        export default function Experience({logged_user}) {
          const [modalShow, setModalShow] = React.useState(false);
          const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
        
    
        return (
            <div className="exp-details">
{experienceArray.map((experience, i) => {
    return(
 <span key={experience.id}>
<div className="exph1">{experience.title} <span onClick={() => setModalShow(true)}><FontAwesomeIcon className="nav-icon float-right text-muted" icon={faPencilAlt} /></span></div>
        <ExperienceEditPopup logged_user={singleUserDetail.actable_id}
      show={modalShow}
      onHide={() => setModalShow(false)}
      />
            <div className="exph2">{experience.company_name}.</div>
            <div className="exph3">{experience.start_year} - {experience.end_year}</div>
            <hr/>
            </span>
             );
              })
              } 
            </div>
                )  
        }
```

ExperienceEditPopup.js

```
import React, {useState, useEffect, Component } from "react";
import axios from 'axios';
import { Modal } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import { faPencilAlt} from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';


const ExperienceEditPopup = props => {
#how to get edit clicked ids based popups here?
  let logged_user_id = props.logged_user;
  let experience_id = # here i need to get the expereince id on each popup click

  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
  const handleClose = () => setShow(false); #here i need to close popups based on edit button click
  const handleShow = () => setShow(true); #here i need to show popups based on edit button click

  const [experienceArray, setexperienceArray] = React.useState([]);
  const getexperienceUserDetails = (experience_id, logged_user_id) => {
    axios
    .get(`http://localhost:3001/users/${logged_user_id}/experiences/${experience_id}`, { withCredentials: true })
    .then((response) => {
      const experienceArray = response.data;
      setexperienceArray(experienceArray);
      console.log(experienceArray);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(" error", error);
    });
  };
  React.useEffect(() => {
   if (experience_id) {
    getexperienceUserDetails(experience_id, logged_user_id);
  }
}, [experience_id,logged_user_id]);
  

  return (
    <Modal {...props} size="lg" aria-labelledby="contained-modal-title-vcenter" centered >
    <div className="modal-header">
    <h5 className="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Edit Experience</h5>
    <button type="button" className="close" onClick={props.onHide} aria-label="Close">
    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
    </div>
    <form onSubmit={handleExperienceEditSubmit}>
        <div className="modal-body">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" defaultValue={experienceArray.title} name="title" onChange={handleChange}  placeholder="Designation" />
          <input type="text" class="form-control" defaultValue={experienceArray.company_name} name="company_name"  onChange={handleChange}  placeholder="Company Name" />
          <input type="text" defaultValue={experienceArray.location} class="form-control" name="location" onChange={handleChange} placeholder="Location"></input>
        </div>

        <div className="modal-footer">
          <span className="btn_cls"><button className="btn save-btn">Save</button></span>
        </div>
    </form> 
    </Modal>
    );
}

export default ExperienceEditPopup;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a single state for all Popups.

```
const [modalShow, setModalShow] = React.useState(false);
```

You could store the `experience.id` so you could render the right modal.

```
const [modalShow, setModalShow] = React.useState(-1);
```

Also, you will need to change the trigger function

```
<span onClick={() => setModalShow(experience.id)}>
```

You may pass the `experience_id` here

```
<ExperienceEditPopup
  logged_user={singleUserDetail.actable_id}
  show={modalShow} 
  onHide={() => setModalShow(false)}
/>
```

Something like:

```
<ExperienceEditPopup
  logged_user={singleUserDetail.actable_id}
  experience_id={experience.id}
  show={modalShow === experience.id}
  setModalShow={setModalShow}
  onHide={() => setModalShow(-1)}
/>
```

Inside your `ExperienceEditPopup` you don't need to control the visibility of it, so you don't need:

```
const [show, setShow] = useState(false)
```

Instead of that you could use the `setModalShow` that you might pass as a props to it.

I think you didn't really understand the code you wrote, ask to clarify your mind before asking for solutions, it's always a better approach

Comment: this passes all experience id from experience component, and gets data of last experience passed id details in popup.

Comment: But you are rendering a modal for each experience, isn't it?

Comment: this passes id before edit click itself, in console it displays all id's that loops through experienceArray. if 2 eperience details all 2 ids,are displayed. but i wnt id on click. i need to pass onclick

Comment: <span onClick={() => setModalShow(true)}> do it here, set whatever you want

Comment: Ohhh, I've noticed the problem here! I am going to edit my answer

Comment: U are really great. Thanks a lot, its working fine. but on close i need to click 2 times to close the modal popup? any idea about that?

Comment: Cool, sorry i didnt see your last comment